# What is the Big O notation for this function?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have written a function and I need to know the big O notation for it.
I have tried to slove this myself and I get O(N^2), however I have been told that this is not the correct answer.

Can someone please tell me what the correct notation is and also a step by step explanation of how they came to that answer?

The function is below.

Thanks in advance

```
    public static string Palindrome(string input) 
    {
        string current = string.Empty;
        string longest = string.Empty;

        int left;
        int center;
        int right;


        if (input == null || input == string.Empty || input.Length == 1)  {   return input;   }


        for (center = 1; center < input.Length -1; center++) 
        {
            left = center - 1;  
            right = center + 1;

            if (input[left] == input[center])
            {
                left--;
            }

            while (0 <= left && right < input.Length) 
            {
                if (input[left] != input[right])
                {
                    break;
                }

                current = input.Substring(left, (right - left + 1));

                longest = current.Length > longest.Length ? current : longest;

                left--;  
                right++;
            }
        }
        return longest;
    }
```

Comment: The first `for` loop gives you `N` iterations. The `while` loop loops `N/2` times worst-case and `1` time best-case.

Comment: @Blender, The while loop takes O(n^2) not O(n), see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is O(n^3) algorithm:

This part takes O(n^2):

> **// O(n) times for while loop**

```
        while (0 <= left && right < input.Length)   
        {
            if (input[left] != input[right])
            {
                break;
            }
```

> **// taking substring is O(n)**

```
            current = input.Substring(left, (right - left + 1)); 

            longest = current.Length > longest.Length ? current : longest;

            left--;  
            right++;
        }
```

Also there is an outer O(n), `for` loop, which causes to O(n*n^2).

You can improve your algorithm by changing this lines:

```
   current = input.Substring(left, (right - left + 1)); 
   longest = current.Length > longest.Length ? current : longest;
```

to:

```
   currentLength = right - left + 1;
   if(currentLength > longest)
   { 
     longest = current.Length > longest.Length ? current : longest;
     longestLeft = left;
     longestRight = right;
   }
```

and finally return a substring from longestLeft to longestRight. Actually avoid to use `substring` method too many times.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had completely overlooked the substring function

Answer (score 0):

The `if (input[left] != input[right])` statement is executed O(n^2) times, and so are the several assignments following it, in particular:

```
current = input.Substring(left, (right - left + 1));
```

In typical implementations of substring functions, a sequence of characters is copied from the string to a new string object.  The copy is an O(n) operation, leading to O(n^3) time for the loops and substring operation.

One can fix the problem by moving  the assignments to `current` and `longest` to after the closing bracket of the `while` construct.  But note that `left--;` and `right++;` will then have executed one time more than in the existing code, so the assignment  to `current` becomes

```
current = input.Substring(left+1, (right-1 - (left+1) + 1));
```

or

```
current = input.Substring(left+1, (right-left-1));
```

Thus, the O(n) substring operation is done at most O(n) times.